# FindFirstFile returns access denied

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I'm trying to create a robust recursive folder deleter function.

With normal directories works pretty fine.

The problem appears when I create a "hardcore" direcory, like:

C:\test\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\ ... \x\x\x

The length of this is around 25000 (less then the MSDN limit: 32,767). Basically I created this directory recursively until the CreatDirectory function failed.

Now, the strangest thing is, that my function is able to delete 2 directories then the FindFirstFile fails with 0x5:

```
\\?\C:\test\x\ ... \x\x\x\*.*    < no error
\\?\C:\test\x\ ... \x\x\*.*      < no error
\\?\C:\test\x\ ... \x\*.*        < access denied
```

(I can rerun the it, the app is slowly chews up the folder, 2 by 2, probably until the path length gets pretty small)

I'm running FindFirstFile to check if the folder is empty.

- Is there any sort of limitation that is less documented?
- The FindFirstFile just simply doesn't work? (buggy?)
- Am I missing some sort of NTFS permission thing?
- Something else ...

**EDIT:
IMPORTANT NOTE: If I run the program step by step slowly ... then nothing will fail.**

Comment: plz show us your stripped code

Comment: The code is huge, & I don't find it usefull to post.

Comment: I've done this exact thing a number of times and never had a problem; the issue is most likely in your code.  At least try reducing it to a minimal example to see if it's something obvious.

Comment: I'm asking for strange unknown things by me that's messing the things. Based on your comment there is none, so I have to fix my code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are probably experiencing something like a virus scanner, indexer or continuous-backup solution holding a handle to the directory. If the Indexing Service is configured to index that folder for example.

Trying to delete a folder or file which is open other than with FILE_SHARE_DELETE flag will cause ACCESS_DENIED.

To confirm this, use Process Monitor to see opens and closes on anything matching your path.

(Of course also confirm you called FindClose).

Comment: The Indexing Service was quering the deepest folder ... always.

Comment: My problem was that the access permissions were wrong on the file i was trying to access. It seems like its a 'duh' solution but i would check the file properties->security and make sure that the correct access group can access the files, as its the most obvious case of 'ACCESS_DENIED', cause...you cannot access the files =P